# Paste column format only through iteration

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that copies data from one workbook to another. Now, the 2nd column in my destination workbook has a certain color format that I need to be applied till the last column with data in it.

This is the code snippet to find the last non-empty column  :

```
Dim rLastCell As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DestName)

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

Dim LastCol As Long        
LastCol = rLastCell.Column      
MsgBox LastCol
```

So, now I want to iterate and paste the format from the 2nd column to all the columns until `LastCol`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are much easier ways to find the last column in a worksheet.

Comment: As I said, any help would be appreciated, if you have an easier way could you please share it? Thank you @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: I think this is what you meant :lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
MsgBox  "Last Column: " & lCol

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.   Dim CopyRng As Range
            Set CopyRng = Wb.Sheets(DestName).Range("B1:B57")
            CopyRng.Copy
            
                For j = 2 To lCol
            
                    Wb.Sheets(DestName).Cells(1, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    
                Next j

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution :

```
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox "Last Column: " & lCol

Dim x As Long 
Columns(2).Copy 
For x = 3 To LastCol 
    Columns(x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 
Next
```